# OVH & CloudFlare: email redirect doesn't work

Tags: mx

I have one domain on OVH.
I use with this domain CloudFlare.

On my domain I need only one email, that I use only for forward.
On OVH the MX record for only forward email is: redirect.ovh.net

I put this MX value in the CloudFlare, but when I send an email, is rejected:

> "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> test@domain.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: 
>   Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server >for the recipient domain domain.com by redirect.ovh.net.
>
> The error that the other server returned was:
>   553 sorry, that domain isn't allowed to be relayed thru this MTA (#5.7.1)"

But if in OVH I activate the free basic hosting (start1m) with is own MX records (mx1.ovh.net and mx2.ovh.net) the email forward work !

The problem is caused because OVH doen't recognize CloudFlare name server ?
How can I resolve this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

OVH mail redirection using `redirect.ovh.net` as MX server works only when you use OVH DNS server. When you add a mail redirection, they add a TXT record with the email to redirect as a subdomain and the redirection as content of the TXT record.
But even if you add this record to your cloudflare account, OVH will not fetch it.

It's by design on their side, so indeed, the easiest solution is to use basic hosting (like start1m) and configure your cloudflare account to use `mx1.mail.ovh.net`.
The other solution is to use their DNS server and not Cloudflare.